# Bug in Google Chrome for Iframes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html graphing calculator that was relatively easy to create. I created an iframe and a textbox that held the code for a viewer to interact with. The system that was working before I put in the textbox and iframe but is now is acting buggy and not working properly. It could be I broke pieces of the code while transferring it, but I could not find the individual problems. The problems I noticed is that the system does not correctly graph on the y axis, whereas it did before (I fixed this problem by dividing the y-axis calculated by 13, but still am interested why it was higher than normal). Also, when I delete a number on one of the inputs after graphing once, the content of the iframe disappears, but reappears when I change the size of the page. Interestingly, if the size of the page is not your regular desktop, it does not disappear(I did not try any larger computers). I thought I may have done something wrong with the z-indexes I set but couldn't find any problems there. Does anyone know why I am running into these problems? Currently I am guessing that is is some king of loading problem for the iframe. The code is below;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>GCalcScratchpad</title>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
            }
            hr {
                border-top: 3px solid #bbb;
            }
            iframe {
                width: 100%;
                height: 600px;
                border: none;
            }
            textarea {
                resize: none;
                float: right;
                width: 80%;
                height: 1800px;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
            }
            div {
                width: 18%;
                float: left;
            }
            button {
                width: 100%;
                text-align: left;
                margin-top: 4px;
            }
            p {
                font-size: smaller;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="program"></iframe>
        <hr>
        <h2>My Coding</h2>
        <div>
            <button onclick="run()">Run Program</button>
            <button onclick="fullScreen()">Fullscreen</button>
            <p>The buttons above will run any changes to the code made in the textbox or resize to fullscreen.</p>
            <p></p>
            <h3>CSS</h3>
            <p>This CSS is mostly beginner friendly, with one aspect of it slightly more complex. The majority of the CSS is me sizing divs and changing the body to a font and background color I like. I use z-index in this program too to make so that the graphed line does not go over text I do not want it to. There is also the #topGraph > div, which makes so that I can create other two pixel by two pixel divs using Javascript. I use this for the graphed line.</p>
            <p></p>
            <h3>HTML</h3>
            <p>The HTML is more beginner friendly, just basic HTML elements. These elements consist of divs (to keep the content uniform and avoid the graphed lines covering other content as well as to create the blank graph), text (to inform the viewer how to use the program), buttons (as a form of text to display the formula and to trigger functions) and inputs for your y-intercept and slope. These simple peices form the basics of the HTML.</p>
            <p></p>
            <h3>Javascript</h3>
            <p>The Javascript is more complex. It uses functions that calculate the basic formula to make the graph and to actually graph the points of the graph. It then uses your button's onclick function to take your input values and runs those values using the functions listed before.</p>
        </div>
        <textarea class="code" id="code">
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            /* This changes the body's font to one I think is more fitting for the program. */
            body {
                font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
                background-color: white;
            }
            /* This changes the width of every div. I use this to make the text look nicer. */
            div {
                width: 400px;
                background-color: #fff;
                z-index: 2;
            }
            /* This div is used in Javascript to create the graphed lines. */
            #topGraph > div {
                height: 2px;
                width: 2px;
                z-index: 0;
            }
            /* This div I use to create the bottom portion of this div. The download for the images I used is below. */
            #bottomGraph {
                position: relative;
                height: 31px; 
                width: 441px; 
                background: url('../Pictures/grid2.png'); 
                margin-left: 10px; 
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                z-index: -2;
            }
            /* This div makes it so that the graphed line does not cover up the text. */
            .noLine {
                width:  550px;
                background-color: #fff;
                z-index: 2;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- This div works similarly to the styling that I used on the divs in general except in CSS I made it slightly wider so that it could hold the length of the formula. -->
        <div class="noLine">
            <!-- This div shortens the width of the text so that it matches the rest of the page. The text inside gives instructions to the viewer which inform him how to use the page. -->
            <div>
                <h2>Slope-Intercept Graphing Calculator</h2>
                <p>Put in your slope and your y-intercept. If you have a direct equation do not leave the y-intercept blank. Instead put in a zero. Then click the run button. Below is the code I used explained.</p>
            </div>
            <!-- The rest of these buttons make a visible formula to the viewer. The inputs have an id so that the Javascript can access their contents. The 'run' button allows the viewer to run the program using a function linked to the onclick aspect. -->
            <button>{ y =</button>
            <input id="slope" />
            <button>x +</button>
            <input id="y_intercept" />
            <button>= ? }</button>
            <button onclick="run()">run</button>
        </div>
        <!-- This div serves as the main graph picture (pictures are available for download below). The styling is in the div itself. -->
        <div id="topGraph" style="position: relative; height: 271px; width: 441px; background: url('../Pictures/grid.png'); margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px; z-index: -1"></div>
        <!-- This div serves as the graph underneath y axis 0. This time the styling is in the style tags. -->
        <div id="bottomGraph"></div>
        <Script>
            // The first function I use is one that calculates the basic formula of a 2-dimensional graph; y=mx+b (basic algebra).
            function calculate_y(m, x, b) {
                return (m*x)+parseFloat(b);
            }
            // Then I create I second function that calculates what answer we would get every time y is given a new value using a for statement. Each new y value is 0.004 higher. Then each value x and y is mapped out on the div 'topGraph' and the point is shown using divs I've shown before in the CSS portion. These divs are solid black and 2 pixels by two pixels. I give it a z-index of -1 so that I can set a div with a background of white to a higher z-index to avoid lines going over that div. I use this to avoid lines going over text that I do not want it to.
            function multiple_x_s(m, b) {
                for (x = -3; x < 10; x += 0.004) {
                    y = calculate_y(m, x, b);
                    var new_div = document.createElement('div');
                    new_div.style.height = 4;
                    new_div.style.width = 4;
                    new_div.style.position = 'absolute';
                    new_div.style.left = x*130+'px';
                    new_div.style.bottom = y*130+'px';
                    new_div.style.background = 'black';
                    new_div.style.zIndex = '1';
                    document.getElementById('topGraph').appendChild(new_div);
                }
            }
            // This function runs when you click the button (via onclick). This function runs the other two functions I described and set certain values using the ids of the input tags.
            function run() {
                var slope = document.getElementById("slope").value; 
                var y_intercept = document.getElementById("y_intercept").value;
                multiple_x_s(slope, y_intercept/13);
            }
        </Script>
    </body>
</html>
        </textarea>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                document.getElementById("program").srcdoc = document.getElementById("code").value
            }
            function run() {
                document.getElementById("program").srcdoc = document.getElementById("code").value
            }
            function fullScreen() {
                document.getElementById("program").requestFullscreen()
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT1; I have tested this on multiple browsers and learned that the problem seems to only occur in Chrome, which leads me to believe that this is a bug in Google Chrome.

EDIT2; I have tested this when the number I delete is zero or letters and the program continues to work. It is only when I delete real numbers that the program fails. I have also tested using different forms of input such as the textarea but this did not fix the problem.

EDIT3; I tried deleting the "DOCTYPE html" tags and the "html" tags and the program still has the same bug. The rest of the program works however.

EDIT4; I tried making so that the overflow of the body is hidden, which seemed to eliminate the problem. I am still unsure what this fixed, but the entire program works now. Thankyou to everyone who helped. :)

Comment: If that's your actual HMTL it's invalid

Comment: How would you fix this, and why does it work on some browsers rather than others?

Comment: I also have not run into any errors.

Comment: Check it w3c, jist because it runs in orher browsers doesnt mean its valid

Comment: You appear to have dumped a complete `<html>` element into a `<textarea>`. That's not a valid HTML structure and what the browser does about it is implementation-dependent. Fix your HTML, then worry about possible browser bugs.

Comment: I checked it in w3c and got the following warning, but nothing challenged the files validity:                                                                                                                                          "This document appears to be written in English. Consider adding lang="en" (or variant) to the html start tag."

Comment: How would you fix this? Is there another way of creating source-code for an iframe that does not mean that I have to create another page and connect the two pages?

Comment: Whatever the rights and wrongs of the code structure, it seems to behave the same for me in Firefox as it does in Chrome. I don't understand why you didn't plot on a <canvas> element.